# Accessing a singleton class in c# with this;

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, instance

While searching for ways to get an instance of a singleton class i found many different approaches (some simple, some convoluted) but when messing around i found a way to do it which i didn't find anywhere else.

So what i basically do is:

```
public class Foo
    { 
       public static Foo Invoker;
       public Foo() 
       {
          Invoker = this;

       }
       public void Method1()
       { 
         //.....
       }
    }
```

And then from another class

```
public class Foo2
    { 

       public Foo2() 
       {
          //.....

       }
       public void Main()
       {
          var foo = Foo.Invoker;
          //or
          Foo.Invoker.Method1();
       }
    }
```

My app is single threaded so i don't care about thread safety (should i?) , so are there any other problems that this approach could cause that i am missing?

Comment: What is stopping people from instantiating a `Foo` themselves? (e.g. `new Foo()`) EDIT: Actually. this won't even work, since the constructor is never called.

Comment: `Foo` is not a singleton

Comment: There is a very nice article from John Skeet about [singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)

Comment: Creating a new instance is not disallowed, but there is no point of doing it, since i want to access already existing values (maybe thats not apparent from my example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your 'singleton' pattern is quite easy to break. Let's say I'd create two instances of `Foo` in your application (changing the name of the class `Foo1` to `Bar` for clarity):

```
var firstFoo = new Foo();

var bar = new Bar();

// Will access firstFoo when it calls Foo.Invoker
bar.Main();

var secondFoo = new Foo();

// Will access secondFoo when it calls Foo.Invoker. Huh?
bar.Main();
```

Another problem: Let's say I use `Bar`, without having initialized any `Foo` instances:

```
var bar = new Bar();

// Will throw a NullReferenceException, because Foo.Invoker is not yet initialized.
bar.Main();
```

As a rough rule of thumb, you should not set static fields from instances, because it leads to these kinds of situations.
Secondly, `Bar` probably does not need to know that `Foo` is a singleton in the first place. You could simply inject `Foo` in `Bar`'s constructor.

```
public class Bar
{ 
    private Foo foo;
    public Bar(Foo foo) => this.foo = foo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));

    public void Main()
    {
        // Now we know it is not null and, for Bar, it does not matter whether it's a singleton or not.
        foo.Method1();
    }
}
```

This way you could manage `Foo` instances easier in your application:

```
var firstFoo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar(firstFoo);

// Does not make a difference now.
var secondFoo = new Foo();
```

This way, you could also leverage dependency injection containers like NInject or Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection to manage your singletons for you.

If you really do want to create a single threaded singleton pattern, I would read Jon Skeet's [blog post](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton) about singletons (good read!).

The simplest way of creating a singleton would be this approach. This way you create a single instance of Foo on the static property, that can never be changed. But read the blog post for more advanced patterns:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo Invoker { get; } = new Foo();

    // Private constructor makes sure the only instance of Foo is created here.
    private Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

### Edit

If you'd want to make sure that all references to `Foo` in your application point to the last created instance of `Foo`, you could try something like this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Method1();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    private static int index = 1;
    private int id;
    private static NestedFoo invoker = new NestedFoo();
    public static IFoo Invoker
    {
        get
        {
            if (invoker.Instance == null)
            {
                Create();
            }

            return invoker;
        }
    }
    private Foo(int id) => this.id = id;
    public static IFoo Create()
    {
        var foo = new Foo(index++);
        invoker.Instance = foo;
        return invoker;
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.id);
    }

    private class NestedFoo : IFoo
    {
        public Foo Instance { get; set; }
        public void Method1() => Instance.Method1();
    }
}
```

Now you'll always have a reference to the same instance of foo:

```
var foo = Foo.Create();
foo.Method1(); // 1
var foo2 = Foo.Create();
foo.Method1(); // 2
foo2.Method1(); // 2
```

Comment: well i figured my method was not foolproof, but what i dont understand is how is that last piece of code so much different from what im doing? 
Is it because my `Invoker = this;` is in the constructor?

Comment: @KyriakosXatzisavvas Yes, that would cause your singleton property to change for every created Foo. Note I added a private constructor in the post now. That way, you can manage the single instance of Foo easily.

Comment: What if i only need the last created instance of Foo?
What im saying is that this works for me because i only need one active instance of Foo , and when i refer to it by Foo.Invoker i know that i always get the last instance 
(i dont exactly care about values from previous instances)

Comment: @KyriakosXatzisavvas I can't think of a situation where that would make sense? That makes things awfully complex. Shouldn't you just pass the `Foo` into the `Main()` method of `Bar`? There must be ways to get around this pattern of you're trying to create. Perhaps you should share the problem you're trying to solve, so we can make suggestions how to improve your design.

Comment: @KyriakosXatzisavvas See my edit for a way to always hold a reference to the same instance of Foo

Comment: Im not really trying to solve a problem, im just looking to make my code more stable, and your code works and it definitely looks more foolproof, so i'll mark it as an answer :)